# using fstring or format causing 404 return in server response

Tags: python, python-3.x, sonarqube

Team,
on linux, Using f-string or format or concatenate in python gets 404 response from server and works when I use values statically. a more strange part is when i run this locally on MAC with fstring it works.

Code I tried is commented

```
GERRIT_CN = os.environ.get('GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER')
GERRIT_PS = os.environ.get('GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER')
sq_url = 'https://sonar.company.com/'
projectKey="team-pba"
gerrit_cn_ps = f"{GERRIT_CN}-{GERRIT_PS}"
print(gerrit_cn_ps)

def sonar_api():
    debug_requests_on()
    sonar = SonarQubeClient(sonarqube_url=sq_url, username=myUsr, password=myPass)
    # project_pull_requests = sonar.qualitygates.get_project_qualitygates_status(projectKey="team-pba", pullRequest="124434-120") < WORKS
    # project_pull_requests = sonar.qualitygates.get_project_qualitygates_status(projectKey=f"{projectKey}", pullRequest=f"{GERRIT_CN}-{GERRIT_PS}") <FAILS
    # project_pull_requests = sonar.qualitygates.get_project_qualitygates_status(projectKey=f"{projectKey}", pullRequest=GERRIT_CN+"-"+GERRIT_PS) < FAILS
    # project_pull_requests = sonar.qualitygates.get_project_qualitygates_status(projectKey=projectKey, pullRequest=gerrit_cn_ps) < FAILS
```

[sonar-python-api](https://python-sonarqube-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/qualitygates.html)

using static values works

```
project_pull_requests = sonar.qualitygates.get_project_qualitygates_status(projectKey="team-pba", pullRequest="124434-139")
```

but same above code used with fstring gets me 404 not sure what is api not liking. any hints or how formatting is replacing string?

on linux jenkins container fails ONLY when I use FSTRING or FORMAT. Works when I put in static values.

```
+ python3.8 /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/sonar-api.py
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sonar.company.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://sonar.company.com:443 "GET /api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=team-pba&pullRequest=124434-139 HTTP/1.1" 404 103
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace///sonar-api.py", line 61, in <module>
    print(sonar_api())
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace///sonar-api.py", line 51, in sonar_api
    project_pull_requests = sonar.qualitygates.get_project_qualitygates_status(projectKey=projectKey, pullRequest=gerrit_cn_ps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sonarqube/utils/common.py", line 132, in inner_func
    response = self._get(url_pattern, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sonarqube/utils/rest_client.py", line 141, in _get
    return self.request("GET", path=path, params=params, data=data, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sonarqube/utils/rest_client.py", line 99, in request
    raise NotFoundError(msg)
sonarqube.utils.exceptions.NotFoundError: Error in request. Possibly Not Found error [404]: Pull request '124434-139' in project 'team-pba' not found
124434-139
send: b'GET /api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=team-pba&pullRequest=124434-139 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: sonar.company.com\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAuthorization: Basic xxxxx\r\n\r\n’
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 404 \r\n'
header: Server: nginx/1.12.2
header: Date: Tue, 28 Mar 2023 21:16:09 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Content-Length: 103
header: Connection: keep-alive
```

Successful log is when using static values.

```
+ python3 /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/sonar-api.py
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sonar.company.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://sonar.company.com:443 "GET /api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=team-pba&pullRequest=124434-139 HTTP/1.1" 200 881
[Pipeline] echo
124434-139
send: b'GET /api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=team-pba&pullRequest=124434-139 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost
[Pipeline] }
```

fresh logs failure on linux using fstring.

```
all values
124434
142
124434-142
send: b'GET /api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=team-pba&pullRequest=124434-142 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: sonar.company.com\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.28.2\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAuthorization: Basic xxxxx\r\n\r\n’
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 404 \r\n'
header: Server: nginx/1.12.2
header: Date: Tue, 28 Mar 2023 21:45:21 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Content-Length: 103
header: Connection: keep-alive
[Pipeline] }
```

fresh logs success on mac using fstring

```
Command> python3 sonar-api.py
all values
124434
142
124434-142
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sonar.company.com:443
send: b'GET /api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=team-pba&pullRequest=124434-142 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: sonar.company.com\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAuthorization: Basic xxxx\r\n\r\n’
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n'
header: Server: nginx/1.12.2
header: Date: Tue, 28 Mar 2023 21:53:55 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Content-Length: 739
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://sonar.company.com:443 "GET /api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=team-pba&pullRequest=124434-142 HTTP/1.1" 200 739
52.53:0.0
```

Comment: Is the curly quote in `projectKey` a copying error or in the real code? Make sure you turn off "smart quotes" when editing code.

Comment: it was copy error. thanks for pointer.

Comment: What are the values when you print `GERRIT_CN`, `GERRIT_PS`, and `gerrit_cn_ps` when using f-strings?

Comment: ran again and post fixed to question in end.`124434-142`

Comment: one finding i observed is, when i ran this on docker container, it failed as usual then i manually exported the `G_CN` and `G_PS` and script worked. so not sure how can i get it to work programmatically as it is called by jenkinsfile. also not sure if python while running is able to fetch vars or not from env?